# Spring REST Docs: special characters are not shown correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

In my Spring MVC Test (UTF-8 encoded) we find:

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity())
        .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation)
    .snippets().withEncoding("UTF-8")) // default
    .build();
...
myRequestDTO.setValue("Größe");
ResultActions action = this.mockMvc
    .perform(post("/my-service")
    .content(jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(myRequestDTO))
...
action.andDo(document("docs"));
```

The asciidoctor file contains

```
HTTP Request
include::{snippets}/docs/http-request.adoc[]
```

After I have rendered it and open the generated HTML file (which is UTF-8 encoded, too) in my firefox browser I find

```
HTTP Request

POST /my-service HTTP/1.1
...
GrÃ¶ÃŸe
```

How can the special chars be displayed correctly?

Comment: When you say you "find in your generated documentation" - how are you opening that? Which encoding are you specifying?

Comment: Do the contents of the `{snippets}/docs/http-request.adoc` file look correct?

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson, no, the adoc file does not look correct: `GrÃ¶ÃŸe`.

Comment: @JohannesFlügel That's almost certainly a bug in REST Docs. Sadly, I'm struggling to reproduce it. Can you please open an issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/new) with a small sample that reproduces the problem? Some information about your OS, its locale, etc would be very useful too.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: here it is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/201

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem here was with the conversion of a request's content as a `byte[]` into a String. Spring REST Docs uses the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` header to determine the `Charset` that should be used when creating the `String`. If there's no `Content-Type` header or its value doesn't have a `charset` attribute, the JVM's default `Charset` is used (as a result of calling `new String(bytes)`).

There are two ways to avoid corruption of special characters:

1. Specify a charset attribute in the request's `Content-Type` header. Use `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` rather than `text/plain`, for example.
2. Configure the JVM's default `Charset` by setting the `file.encoding` system property. `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

After I have called `prettyPrint()` it works:

```
action.andDo(document("docs", 
    preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
    preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));
```

Comment: I am not quite satisfied with this solution. The webservice returns the posted `myRequestDTO` in the response's body. Then we find `Gr??e` in the HTML document. Without `preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())` we find the correct `Größe`. Unfortunately the addition of `replacePattern(Pattern.compile("Gr.+e"), "Größe")` to `preprocessResponse` does not help.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary so, if it is, I think you've found a bug. I'd open (and hopefully fix) one myself, but I'm struggling to reproduce the behaviour that you're seeing.